# Strange PHP parse error when creating a contact form

Tags: php, html, forms

For some reason I keep getting an error within my backend code for my contact form

Here is my contact form

```
  <div id = "form">

<form action ="contact2.php" method="post">
Hi Rebekah My Name Is
<br>
<input type="text" name="name">
<br>
My Email Is
<br>
<input type="text" name="email">
<br>
My Message Is
<br>
<TEXTAREA NAME="message" ROWS=6 COLS=40>
</TEXTAREA>

<br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

<?php 
include "contact2.php";
echo $result; 

?>

</div>
```

Here is my backend PHP code

```
<?php

$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];

$mail_to = 'example@yahoo.com';

$subject = 'Message from a site visitor ' . $field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);


// Check if name has been entered
if (!$_POST['name']) {
    
$field_name = 'Please enter your name';
}
 
// Check if email has been entered and is valid
if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $email = 'Please enter a valid email address';
}
 
//Check if message has been entered
if (!$_POST['message']) {
    $field_message = 'Please enter your message';
}

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$field_name && !$email && !$field_message) {
    if (mail ($_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    } 
?>
```

When I run the code there is said to be an error in my php code on line 43 which is the last line but I can't seem to see what the problem is as this is only the closing tag for the php code, when I take the closing php tag out I still get the same message.

Here is the message that is displayed.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in D:\contact2.php on line 43

I have taken out where the file is found from the above for safety reasons.

Comment: You aren't closing your last `if` statement.

Comment: After adding that in I now get loads of errors :-(

Comment: That's because your code probably has more errors, but fixing that first one lets the code actually be readable by the server. Open another question if you get stuck fixing them and i'll be happy to help!

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing tag of your `if` statement.

Add `}` before your closing tag `?>` on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if (!$field_name && !$email && !$field_message) {` is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your last IF statement is lacking a `}`

```
if (!$field_name && !$email && !$field_message) {
    if (mail ($_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
} // <-----
```